# jquery Struts2 jquery-easy-ui

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, struts2, jquery-easyui

I'm using struts2 jquery plugin and also using jquery easy ui. The plugin to work assumes that I include the tag: `<sj:head jqueryui="true" defaultLoadingText="Please wait ..."/>` at the top of the jsp page

the problem is that when I include this tag the javascript that depands on jquery easy ui stops to work.
My question is: Is there is anyway to use both jquery plugin and jquery easy ui without problems?

Comment: could you provide us the code of the jquery easy ui?

Comment: You'll need to provide more details, like the order in which you're including the JS files, etc. Also, the version that jQuery EasyUI depends on would be good to know.

Comment: well i'm using a jquery struts2 plugin which includes a customized ui libraries and it conflicts with the jquery origional library

Answer (score 0):

have you tried **jquery.noConflict**?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```